# Is it possible in the real universe for a planet to develop a thick Octaoxygen atmosphere?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, planets, atmosphere, oxygen

I know how weird this question sounds and how the answer to it is probably **NO** at first glance, but I don't know enough about octaoxygen and oxygen to be 100% sure about the answer being **NO** and honestly, I have some hope (not much) about the answer to this question being **YES** due to the inmense size of the universe and how many planets there is out there.
Even if the possibilities for a planet developing such an atmosphere are ridiculously low and crazy like just a 0.0000000000001% chance for a planet developing it, that's enough since that would mean there would be around as much as 700000 of them just in the entire obserbable universe! (700000 because there is an estimate of around 700000000000000000000 planets in the observable universe)

Here is the best source of information about this molecule I have found so far, there is not a lot of information about it somewhere else: (Yes, wikipedia lol) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octaoxygen

BTW I would coincidere a **maybe, perhaps, possibly or im not 100% sure** answer as a good answer as far as you give a good explanation or your theory as of why you think it may or may not exist. At the end of the day you can't almost never be sure enough about this stuff for a solid YES or NO since we as species don't know enough about the universe in general. Thanks in advance!
*(Also sorry if if I made any grammar mistake, my english is not perfect since it's not my main language)*

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The real question is how can a planet have a partial pressure of oxygen of 100,000 atmospheres. (That looks very much like a bigggg gas giant to me.) (Ah, and BTW, at the pressure where red oxygen forms, oxygen is a solid. Not a gas. You cannot have an atmosphere of it, because it is a solid.)

Comment: Downvoting: 95% of your post is just you saying how desperate you are for any glimmer of hope. The other 5% is a link to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

### Different fine structure constant

It [has been reported](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/09/100909004112.htm) that the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) varies throughout the universe.  The fine structure constant affects things like [how many elements can be found in the periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynmanium).  Whether this variation could change the rules of chemistry so much that octaoxygen would work more like our sulfur, be something close to stable, somewhere far beyond the stars we can ever hope to see?  You'll need a real physicist for that one!

Comment: WOW had no idea about that study, that really does change everything! Thanks for sharing that.
Yeah I know, I went a bit too crazy with that question there since octaoxygen is an obviously not very common molecule and we also don't know a lot about it. Now I think about it, maybe even physicists would have a hard time answering it ...and the "Laws of physics vary throughout the universe" study makes that answer even more uncertain or perhaps impossible lol
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'd suggest rewording the first sentence to something like "At least one study has found that . . ." to emphasize that there's not a scientific consensus behind the variation (and looking at some of their plots, I wouldn't say it's anywhere near conclusive - take a couple data points away and the trend largely disappears). It's an interesting possibility, just not confirmed.

Comment: I think "has been reported" expresses sufficient skepticism.  More to the point, for hard sci-fi you don't *need* a consensus of sources - by the time you have that, it's barely even sci-fi any more.  For this purpose you can pick a source you like and say, "this *could* be true..."

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a planet. There can be no celestial bodies at 10.000 earth mass, with room temperature at the surface. Jupiter has about 800 Earth masses and an object 3-4 times Jupiter mass would become a dwarf star, burning deuterium. Pressure is in the right order, but the surface is too hot to accommodate the O8. I think you'd be talking a cooled down larger star, in the process of collapse. 10000 times earth mass, say about 1/10th of earth radius.. in this case, any chemical element landing on the surface would get subject to enormous pressure and condensate. A layer of condensated - solid - oxigen *could* be the result, when large amounts of oxigen from a nearby gas cloud would collide with it. However, it will be blue rather than red oxigin: the other requirement for O8 (very low temperature) would never be met near the surface of a collapsing star.

Answer (score -1):

Octaoxygen forms from oxygen at [a pressure of ten gigapascals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octaoxygen), or a pressure equal to 10,000 standard atmospheres. <s>Since atmospheric pressure is directly related to gravity, you would need an oxygen-rich atmosphere on a planet with gravity 10,000 times stronger than that of the Earth.</s> Edit: Gravity is a significant factor, but it is not the only one.

The ideal gas law is written PV = nRT, or pressure = number of mols of gas x constant x temperature ÷ volume, which means that pressure does change with temperature, amount of gas, and the volume the gas is contained in. A planet with higher gravity would effectively reduce the volume, which increases the pressure. However, it is not the only variable.

Note that the high proportion of oxygen in Earth's atmosphere is due mostly to plant life and other organisms performing photosynthesis. However, photosynthesis requires sunlight which would not be able to penetrate very far through such a dense atmosphere. Therefore, any organisms would have to be buoyant enough to float near the surface of the planet's atmosphere. This is not as difficult as it seems, since the atmosphere will be around ten times denser than water at sea level on earth - most organisms on Earth would float near its surface. Life also usually requires water, but most water on Earth comes from comet trails as they pass nearby. A gas giant might have enough water vapor in the atmosphere to support floating life.

Comment: Atmospheric is only weakly related to gravity. The primary factor in determining atmospheric pressure is simply the amount of gas in the atmosphere. For example, Venus has the same gravity as Earth, but very much higher atmospheric pressure -- simply because it has a lot more has in the atmosphere.

Comment: You are right. My original source only stated how gravity affected pressure, not that it was the only factor, and I misinterpreted that answer. I have edited my original answer to be more accurate.